# How do you stop onload from repeating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code to replace the src of the iframe to have a random video each time the page is loaded. However the page just keeps loading and keeps running the function. How do I stop the function for repeating.

```
<div id="rightsugg"><iframe id="randomVideo" width="560" height="315" src="" onLoad="displayRandomVideo();" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        function getRandomVideo() {
                            var videos = [
                                'https://www.youtube.com/embed/kiTO7c_qeZs',
                                'https://www.youtube.com/embed/z4Hfv00eqoI',
                                'https://www.youtube.com/embed/7cdZYQB5ONE',
                                'https://www.youtube.com/embed/i1gE3nyQnKg',
                            ];
                            var video = videos[Math.floor(Math.random()*videos.length)];

                            return video;
                        }

                        function displayRandomVideo() {
                            var htmlVideo = document.getElementById("randomVideo");
                            htmlVideo.src = getRandomVideo();
                        }
                        displayRandomVideo();
                    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just unregister the onLoad event after the videa has been displayed.

```
function displayRandomVideo() {
        var htmlVideo = document.getElementById("randomVideo");
        htmlVideo.src = getRandomVideo();
        htmlVideo.onload=null;  
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2r6gvo6j/)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using onload event of the **iframe** in the first place?

```
$(window).load(displayRandomVideo);
```

would do it, and just remove the onload attribute in the <iframe> tag.